# python socket- send() command doesnt work

Tags: python, sockets, send, recv, python-os

i need to write a server and a cliet which do 4 things
1.send the time the message was recived
2.get all the files in a folder
3.copy a file from that folder and create a new file(txt) in another folder
4. close the progrem

clint:

```
    import socket
    import os
    import pickle
    s=socket.socket()
    addr=('127.0.0.1',8200)
    s.connect(addr)
    choice="0"
    while choice!="4":
        print s.recv(4068)
        choice=raw_input("please choose a service number:")
        s.send(choice)
        if choice=="3":
            fileName=raw_input("please enter the name of the file you want to download:")
            s.send(fileName)
        data2= s.recv(4068)
        if choice=="1":
            print data2
        elif choice=="2":
            data_arr=pickle.loads(data2)
            print data_arr
        elif choice=="3":
            text=s.recv(4068)
            if text=="no file with this name":
                print text
            else:          
                newFile=open("newFile.txt","w")
                newFile.write(text)
                newFile.close()       

    print "thanks for using our conection"
    s.close()
```

server:

```
import socket
import time
import os
import pickle
def main():
    path="C:\hello"
    s=socket.socket()
    addr=('127.0.0.1',8200)
    s.bind(addr)
    s.listen(5)
    s2,addr2=s.accept()
    choice="0"
    while choice!="4":
        s2.send("1.Get the time of the message\r\n2.Get list of files\r\n3.Download file\r\n4.Close") 
        choice= s2.recv(4068)
        if choice=="1":
            s2.send(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
        if choice=="2":
            dirs=os.listdir(path)
            data_string = pickle.dumps(dirs)
            s2.send(data_string)    
        if choice=="3":
              fileName=s2.recv(4068)
              os.chdir(path)
              dirs=os.listdir(path)
              for file in dirs:
                  if fileName in dirs:
                      f=open(fileName,'r')
                      text=f.read()
                      **s2.send(text)**
                      f.close()
                  else:
                      **s2.send("no file with this name")**
    s.close()
    s2.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the problem is that i tried it on another pc and the progrem just didnt send the message(in Bold) and i cant understand why because the code works on an another pc and after a few tests i know that it found the file and everything is okay, it just doesnt send the message(the .txt file is not empty)

Comment: This seems problematic, is there any reason you are choosing to use a raw TCP socket rather than something like HTTP? There are a number of frameworks which would make that trivial.

Comment: im a student, and im just learning sockets, that all that we have learnt and we were asked to write it that way..

Comment: well, I can't ethically help too much with homework, but something I did notice is that you are calling `sock.read()` like its definitely going to have data. This is not always the case. Network latency exists and it sucks...you might have to wait for the data to come in...a `while` loop might help in this case.

Comment: i tried to put a timer for a second and it didnt really help, its not really homework also, that just the way we were thought and i dont know another way to write it... the problem is that when i try it on my pc it works just fine no problems at all, but when i tried to show it to a friend in class it just didnt send anything with `s2.send()`

Comment: Do you leave it bound to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: yeah, its local ip at every pc, i use the same local ip and port in the computer in class, i just found out the gmail can do something weird with your code and lines, could it be that?

Comment: the message that i recive is the one above, the first one with the services that  send right after the while.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you checked whether `fileName` in `dirs` or not. You implemented both if and else conditions.  One thing you didn't check is `dirs` itself.

You mentioned that the code works on your machine but not on a 2nd machine. My guess is `dirs` on 2nd machine is empty. Therefore the code ignores all code `for fileName in dirs:`

You can add debug lines to check whether dirs is empty